# Usage of "for whom"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- This is the person **for whom** I have been looking. (I have been
>   **looking for** someone and this person is the one.)
>
> 2- People will now vote **for whom** they are told, forced to vote by
>   people who have a hold over them. (People will now **vote for** someone
>   because people are told to vote for that person.)

---

I feel like these two usages of "**for whom**" are not exactly the same.

I think in the first sentence I can replace the "**for**" as in:
1a- This is the person **whom** I have been looking **for**.

As for the second sentence, I don't think I can replace it as I just did to the first one. I think in the second sentence "**for**" have to be placed right next to the "**vote**" they are a compound phrase- "**vote for**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the person I have been looking for.

Right.

> This is the person whom I have been looking for.

"whom" is not really required here, but ok.  In casual speech, most people would say "who" because the word "whom" is progressing towards obsolescence.

> This is the person for whom I have been looking.

Sounds unusual. Not a typical phrasing.

> People will now vote for whom they are told

Ok

> As for the second sentence, I don't think I can replace it

You have not written an example sentence 2a which we can comment on. But yes - "vote for" does go together. You can't re-order it like "vote him for".